# Set property in class extension via method in class category

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I have a class (`SomeClass`) that I am extending and adding a property (`propOne`) to.
I also want to add a category (`CategoryName`) on this class to create a method that modifies the property added in the extension.

I'm getting a compiler error message saying `[SomeClass setPropOne:] unrecognized selector...`

I'm pretty new to objective-c - how can a method created in a category modify a property added via an extension?

I think what I'm trying to do can be best explained with code:

```
@interface SomeClass ()

@property (nonatomic,weak) id propOne

@end

...
...


@implementation SomeClass (CategoryName)

- (void)someMethodWithParam:(id)param
{
 self.propOne = param;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add an `@property` to a category out of the box. However there is a workaround that involves creating something like this:

```
static const char kMyChar;
```

And binding it to the category (making it an "associated object") via something like this:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kMyChar, alertWrapper, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Take a look [here](http://nscookbook.com/2013/04/ios-programming-recipe-22-simplify-uialertview-with-blocks/) for complete documentation of a good example that "adds a property" to a block-based `UIAlertView` category...

Answer (score 0):

The auto-synthesis mechanism can synthesize a property declared in a class extension only if the class extension is visible when the implementation is compiled. So if the class extension shown in your example was either in **SomeClass.h** or **SomeClass.m**, the property would be synthesized.

Otherwise, the class extension is providing a declaration for a (in this case at least) non-existent property, which is why you're seeing a runtime exception when you try to access it. To fix that, you could implement the accessor methods yourself in the `SomeClass (CategoryName)` category.

The problem you may be facing then is that is that there's no way for a given class to add an instance variable to another class. See Alfie Hansen's answer for a possible workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation to do what you want by using *associated object*.
https://github.com/kissrobber/DProperty